# Can't get rid of double cursors on tags in Visual Studio Code

Tags: double, cursors

I have this problem just recently whenever I click on one tag, say a `<div>`, it automatically puts cursors on both the starting `<div>` and the ending `</div>` all together. 
I have tried re-install vscode itself, deleted settings, un-installed extensions, none of it worked.

Still couldn't find a solution ...
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image: image attched]

When I paste classes, because of the double cursors at the divs, it will end up like this:

[image: second image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` in Settings and uncheck it

[image]